# Is there any method/module/library to directly solve an SDE in python? Especially if it's just geometric brownian motion

Tags: programming, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, differential-equations

Now, I'm given an SDE $$dS_t = 2S_t\,dt + 4 S_t\,dW_t$$ which I need to find the solution of. I have the solution on paper, but I want to know if there's any way I can solve this directly in python. Or indirectly as well if I need to hard code it. I'm guessing scipy should help, but I think I've mostly only found information on how to solve *ordinary* differential equations, not stochastic ones. I would really appreciate if anyone could help me figure out what I'll need to do/tell me how to code this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion for solution (as SDE, not ODE nor PDE). Python code for path simulation is available there too.

Comment: @ir7 Ah yes, you're right, thank you. 
I see how that can simulate/plot it, but I don't believe it can help me *find* the solution? Is there any way I can do that particularly?

Comment: What do you mean by *solution* of an SDE ? Numerical solution or symbolic solution or ... ?

Comment: Analytical solution perhaps? Can you give us the underlying properties of S_t?

Comment: @noob2 yeah no, so i needed an analytic solution. Or I guess a numerical might work, but I don't think it was required, so I won't look into that for now

Comment: @wecandothis weren't given any particular properties of S_t, but yeah I ended up hardcoding it, which worked. If there's any other method though, please do let me know!